# Unique job data in beanstalkd

Tags: mq, beanstalkd

I've been testing beanstalkd today and I am wondering is there anyway possible to make job data unique on beanstald tube? In other words, is it possible to make the tube have only unique values? If no, maybe someone could suggest me similar MQ system which have this feature.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: how do you define unique message? also please provide the nature of the problem you try to achieve, and why you need unique messages, as the request is off for any messaging queue.

Comment: Hello, well what I want to achieve is that tube would only have unique values. For example, if tube's job data is "1", then "2", then "3", I would like that there would be no possibility to add "1" for example. I am planning to use this queue for sending emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you are looking for is a `SET` and not a QUEUE.

- Sets doesn not allow duplicate members.
- Redis has Sorted Sets if you want to keep an order as in the queue

You can achieve what you want with Redis, read about Data types here:
http://redis.io/topics/data-types

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) I found that SPOP can return random element from the set and then remove it, which sounds perfect for me. Just one question - my system will have 20-30 workers which will send SPOP almost on the same time, so is it possible that Redis will return the same value for some of the workers?

Comment: Redis is single threaded, so only one client is working 'at a
time', and the pop operation is atomic.